# Navigation drawer closed after opening a screen from it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented a Navigation Drawer in my app.

There I have included a column as menu with some options

Here you have a screenshot from the Navigation Drawer:

[image]

If I click on an option a new screen is opened

[image]

The isssue I need to solve is that when the user clicks on the back button of that screen, the app shows the default screen not the navigation drawer.

What should I do to go back to the navigation drawer when clicking on the back button?

EDIT

This is how am I calling each class to be opened from the Navigation Drawer:

```
void onItemPressed(BuildContext context, {required int index}){
    Navigator.pop(context);

    switch(index){
      case 1:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const GestionUsuariosInternos()));
        break;
      case 2:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const GestionUsuariosExternos()));
        break;
      case 3:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const GestionUsuariosVisitantes()));
        break;
      case 4:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const GestionEmpresas()));
        break;
      case 8:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  Mapa()));
        break;
    }
  }
```

EDIT

This is the code from one of the pages that is opened from the navigation drawer

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Mapa extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Mapa> createState() => MapaState();
}

class MapaState extends State<Mapa> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  static final CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black, //change your color here
        ),
        title: Text("Sample"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: Text('To the lake!'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, share the code of this page you're trying to change

Comment: @LuisUtrera, the issue happens with any page, I guess the issue is not in the opened page, but in the way I am opening the pages from the navigation drawer

Comment: what I want to see is the onTap parameter of these pages back button or the button itself

Comment: @LuisUtrera, ok, let me put the code from the Map page

Comment: @LuisUtrera, done, you have the code inside my question as edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something called `WillPopScope` widget for that,
you can perform any operation when pressed back button.

You should wrap you screens with this widget and should make Navigation drawer available to every screen.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

Comment: I agree, a `WillPopScope` will allow you to execute code or do the default behavior when the user presses the back button, and should solve your problem

Comment: I have implemented WillPopScope now, but it only gives me the option to return false at onWillPop, I don´t know how to go back to the navigation drawer. Puttint Navigator.of(context).pop, brings me to a blank screen

Comment: want to open Navigation drawer when pressed back right?
then make Navigation drawer available for every screen then when pressed back try to open it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use `WillPopScope` widget to handle backbutton press event.Wrap the the `WillPopScope` widget on root of the pages widget. like this

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        _globalkey.currentState?.openDrawer();
        // Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: new Scaffold(
        key: _globalkey,
        drawer: Drawers.getDrawer(context),
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black, //change your color here
          ),
          title: Text("Pag1"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**to open a drawer while press backbutton**

```
   _globalkey.currentState?.openDrawer();
```

_globalkey is `scaffoldstate` type `Globalkey` .you can declare it inside the widget page class or outside.

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

**Sample Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MYAppWithoutFlicker()));
}

class MYAppWithoutFlicker extends StatefulWidget {
  MYAppWithoutFlicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MYAppWithoutFlicker> createState() => _MYAppWithoutFlickerState();
}

class Drawers {
  static Widget getDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      child: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Mapa()));
              },
              title: Text(
                "Pag1",
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page1()));
              },
              title: Text("Pag2"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
              },
              title: Text("Pag3"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MYAppWithoutFlickerState extends State<MYAppWithoutFlicker> {
  // var decode = (bytes, {allowUpscaling, cacheHeight, cacheWidth}) {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _globalkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawers.getDrawer(context),
      body: ListView(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        // shrinkWrap: false,
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
              10,
              (index) => Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Card(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        index.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {}
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        _globalkey.currentState?.openDrawer();
        // Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: new Scaffold(
        key: _globalkey,
        drawer: Drawers.getDrawer(context),
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black, //change your color here
          ),
          title: Text("Pag1"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      // key: _globalkey,
      drawer: Drawers.getDrawer(context),
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black, //change your color here
        ),
        title: Text("Pag2"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class Mapa extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Mapa> createState() => MapaState();
}

GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class MapaState extends State<Mapa> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: new Scaffold(
        key: _globalkey,
        drawer: Drawers.getDrawer(context),
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black, //change your color here
          ),
          title: Text("Sample"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: _goToTheLake,
          label: Text('To the lake!'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () {
        _globalkey.currentState?.openDrawer();
        // Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
        return Future.value(false);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {}
}
```